# ¿Por qué te introducen con una coma, vocativo?

Tags: gramática, ortografía, puntuación, vocativos

En el artículo [*¿Tiene los días contados la coma del vocativo?*](https://www.yorokobu.es/coma-del-vocativo/) de Mar Abad en Yorokobu hablan del poco uso que se le da a la coma del vocativo, últimamente.

Es decir, se defiende y recuerda el uso correcto a la hora de introducir los vocativos, que son introducidos por una coma:

> Buenos días, princesa.

en lugar de:

> <strike>~Buenos días princesa.</strike>

Efectivamente, el DPD lo explica en su artículo [*coma*](https://www.rae.es/dpd/coma):

> 1.2.3. **Se aíslan entre comas los sustantivos que funcionan como vocativos**, esto es, que sirven para llamar o nombrar al interlocutor: *Javier, no quiero que salgas tan tarde; Has de saber, muchacho, que tu padre era un gran amigo mío; Venid aquí inmediatamente, niños*. Cuando los enunciados son muy breves, se escribe igualmente coma, aunque esta no refleje pausa alguna en la lectura: *No, señor; Sí, mujer*.

Entiendo su uso y lo mantengo en mi escritura tanto como puedo. Ahora bien, la duda que me surge es: ¿por qué es necesaria esa coma? ¿Es para dar expresión gráfica a la pausa que se hace al pronunciarlo?

Answer (score 4):

Como tu propia cita del DPD expresa, se trata de una convención. “Cuando los enunciados son muy breves, se escribe igualmente coma, aunque esta no refleje pausa alguna en la lectura” implica que no se está necesariamente dando expresión gráfica a una pausa.

Yo vengo peleando una batalla desigual en favor del uso prescriptivo y contra la costumbre cada vez más extendida de omitir la coma, y perdiéndola, porque simplemente no le veo el sentido y se ve muy raro, y hasta pedante, usarla cuando nadie más la usa en casos como “Hola, X” o “Buenos días, X”.

Que se trate de una convención y que a veces no indique nada “real” no implica que sea inútil, como lo muestra el ejemplo de confusión que también citaste. Si bien no es muy frecuente, en conversaciones por WhatsApp me ha pasado de tener que repreguntar a alguien qué quiso decir, porque si a la falta de la coma se le suma no ponerle tilde a “sí” ni a “mí”, no respetar la diferencia entre “sino” y “si no”, y otros errores y elipsis menores, el cerebro ya no tiene de dónde agarrarse para resolver las ambigüedades.

Cuando la coma aísla palabras o frases cortas sueltas en medio de una oración o al final, el uso prescriptivo sigue siendo bastante respetado, según me parece, porque en esos casos el hablante sí percibe una pausa y (creo) también se da cuenta de que podría ocasionar ambigüedades o errores sin la coma (“Vamos a comer, gente” vs. “Vamos a comer gente”).

Cuando se trata de expresiones como “por favor” (o “porfa” o “porfi”), que no son vocativos y que están fuera de la estructura sintáctica básica de la frase, es normal que el hablante relaje la norma.

Comment: enorme el ejemplo de _vamos a comer[,] gente_. Mi duda se remontaría algo más atrás: ¿por qué es convención? Es decir, ¿qué problema se quería atajar al ponerla? Pues ahora contamos con ella y visualmente la _necesitamos_ porque hemos aprendido que debe estar allí.